# Boost compilation failed on ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost

I am trying to install boost libraries 1.49.0 on a machine running ubuntu server 14.04. The compilation of boost fails with the following errors.

```
...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/locale/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/threading-multi/icu/formatter.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/locale/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_locale.a(clean) for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/locale/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/threading-multi>icu/formatter.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/locale/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_locale.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/locale/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/threading-multi>icu/formatter.o...
...skipped <p/usr/local/lib>libboost_locale.a for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/locale/build/gcc-4.8/release/link-static/threading-multi>libboost_locale.a...
...failed updating 2 targets...
...skipped 6 targets...
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Alternatively,  try to boostrap with `--without-icu` (of course, only if you don't need the advanced features in Boost Locale)

Comment: @user657267 Do you mean installing libicu-dev? Its already installed.

Comment: I installed ICU as well as tried -without-icu, but still the same error. What are the pre-requisites for the boost installation? 
I need to install boost 1.49.

Comment: Why do you need boost 1.49 specifically?

Comment: @Griwes I am using some old dependencies, which uses older boost (boost 1.49) and are not compatible with newer versions of boost.

Comment: It is not with a particular version.  I am having the exact same error message with boost 1.58,59,60 on ubuntu latest version.  I must be missing some dependency.

Answer (score 4):

As always, I heartily recommend cheating to get the dependencies for any library:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libboost-all-dev
```

Note for clarity: this just makes sure that all dependencies that would be necessary to build the distro's packaged version of Boost are present. As such, it's just a shortcut for installing all these dependencies manually.

In particular, it will fix the missin ICU dependency, so you can compile successfully, whichever (modified?) version of boost you wish to compile.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. Although it installed some dependencies but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you run ./bootstrap.sh again?

Comment: Yes I run ./bootstrap.sh again, but I am still getting the same error :(

Comment: I need to install boost 1.49. Does sudo apt-get build-dep libboost-all-dev works for boost 1.49 as well?

Comment: @shaikh Please refer to the **[lengthy discussion we had](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60248/discussion-between-sehe-and-dirk-eddelbuettel)** here, originally (I wonder how you missed that? ) Also, didn't you say "I tried this"? (Hint: **"Yes."**)

Comment: Yes I tried this but it did not work. I just realized that when I run ./bootstrap.sh, I get this error/warning message "Unicode/ICU support for Boost.Regex?... not found." Do I need to fix this first?

Comment: @shaikh Actually, no, it should just skip compilation of Boost Locale. Alternatively, you can use the hint I commented 2 days ago: **[_Alternatively, try to boostrap with `--without-icu` (of course, only if you don't need the advanced features in Boost Locale)_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560514/boost-compilation-failed-on-ubuntu-server-14-04/25568272?noredirect=1#comment39937043_25560514)**

Comment: I tried "./bootstrap.sh -without-icu", but still the "./b2 install" fails with above errors. Please help... its wasting a lot of my time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60386/discussion-between-shaikh-and-sehe).

Comment: This strategy works and is a by-pass of the true problem associated with boost make system. In my system I got two failed targets after giving the command ./b2 install.  The problems is that b2 does not tell me exactly targets that is broken.  Usually this is due to some dependencies not being installed. It would be nice that b2 should print out the exact dependencies needed.  Any way, if you don't need the failed targets, which is usually the case, you still get a functional boost to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

In case you really need or want Boost release 1.49, you can [find it here via the packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/saucy/boost1.49) search feature.

But as you are already on Ubuntu 14.04, why not just use Boost 1.54?  Using the package will lead to automatic upgrades, so with the next Ubuntu release you get Boost 1.55 and so on.

Comment: Hmm. I didn't know about this. Is there a way to get that on trusty too? Or is it just "luck" that this particular package version is available in saucy? (Hmm. 14.04 is trusty anyways; do you suggest manually downloading the debs?)

Comment: You can almost always use older release. And yes, they tend to still be on the mirrors under the respective release names, see eg [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libboost-all-dev&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) for all known `libboost-all-dev` pointing back all the way.  We do one better in Debian thanks to the fantastic http://snapshot.debian.org which keeps all released versions of all packages.

Comment: Nice. I'll give Debian another go next time around. I like the convenience of that

Comment: I tried the boost release from your mentioned source, but the compilation is still giving me same error. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you install `libboost-all-dev` ?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Is there a way that one can install a higher version using apt-get? 
I'm on ubuntu 14.04 and I need to get bosst 1.55 +, unfortunately as you mentioned, ubuntu 14.04 installs 1.54 using apt-get.
Is there a way to get around this ? and instead of 1.54 get e.g. 1.55 or 1.58?